# Add run with run with elevated privileges for spservices?

Tags: permissions, jquery, spservices

I am unable to add users to the group using custom button and SPServices,only site administrators can only able to add the users to the group.can any one help me how to add the  run with elevated privileges spservices

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do impersonation or permission elevation in Client side object model.

Please refer below mentioned links

[Elevating Permissions with SharePoint’s Web Services](http://sympmarc.com/2011/05/27/elevating-permissions-with-sharepoints-web-services/)

[Elevating privileges using spservices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/392133)

Answer (score 0):

The SPServices library is only allowing you to do what is available through the web services.

A workaround, but not really recommended, would be to create a custom permission level that granted the ability to manage permissions and add users into this group. That would allow them to then execute your code.